# Get list of list with same complex objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

considering the following List of objects:

```
Obj1 - X = 1, Y = 1
Obj2 - X = 1, Y = 1
Obj3 - X = 1, Y = 1
Obj4 - X = 2, Y = 1
Obj5 - X = 2, Y = 1
```

I want to achieve this (two lists with the same objects):

```
L1 - Obj1, Obj2, Obj3
L2 - Obj4, Obj5
```

I did this lambda expression, but it doesn't works:

```
var grouped = ListOfItens.GroupBy(x => ListOfItens.Where(y => new { y.X, y.Y} == new { x.X, x.Y }));
```

I'm pretty sure that the problem is in my Group by condition, but I can't figure out what it is!

Thanks!

Comment: `GroupBy(x => new { x.X, x.Y });` Also what is the expected output? This will just group the data then you will have to project it accordingly using `Select`.

Comment: can you say you want to have lists with identical objects? `GroupBy` will collapse your identical objects

Comment: Can you describe in words what your grouping criteria is?

Comment: @RahulSingh you are awesome! I'm aready using select to reach my list of list! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have to provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<YourClass>` for the overload of `Enumerable.GroupBy`, override `Equals`+`GetHashCode` in that class or use an anonymous type for the `GroupBy` which works if the properties' types override `Equals`+`GetHashCode`(which is the case for `System.Int32`).

Assuming that you want to create a `List<List<YourClass>>`:

```
List<List<YourClass>> grouped = ListOfItens
    .GroupBy(x => new {x.X, x.Y})
    .Select(g => g.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `GroupBy` in this way

```
var grouped = ListOfItens.GroupBy(y => new { y.X, y.Y});
```